# Adjust the direction of my 3D texture

Tags: texturing, 3d-printing

I am trying to get a leather texture on my part with the aim of 3d printing it. I am totally new to blender. Got a pretty good result already, but the problem is that it does a displacement for the whole part from 1 direction. So all the vertical parts of the part are good but the horizontal parts are not (see picture 1).
[image]

I tried to solve this by working with two vertex groups (one for the horizontal and one for the vertical). This worked for the vertical parts (see picture 2) but it still does not work for the horizontal ones (see picture 3). I have also played with the "direction" option in the displacement function but this still does not work.
[image]
[image]

Can someone tell me how to adjust the direction of my texture?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the displace texture in the texture panel?

Comment: You can solve this with a proper UVMap https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/introduction.html